# node-postgres: done() - undefined is not a function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am having a problem with my query function using [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres).

Selects, inserts and deletes all successfully perform the database query, but inserts and deletes trigger this error on the node server:

```
/vagrant/catalog/database/db.js:11
                done();
                ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at null.callback (/vagrant/catalog/database/db.js:11:17)
    at p.handleReadyForQuery (/vagrant/catalog/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:78:10)
    at null.<anonymous> (/vagrant/catalog/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:111:24)
    at emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/vagrant/catalog/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:47:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
```

Here is the query function:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var connectionString = 'postgres://vagrant:vagrant@localhost:5432/catalog';

module.exports = {
    query: function(text, values, callback) {
        pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
            client.query(text, values, function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                done();
                callback(err, result);
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Which is being called by endpoints such as:

```
app.delete(api + '/games/:id', function(req, res) {
    query('DELETE FROM videogame WHERE id=$1', [req.params.id], function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return res.json({'success': true});
    });
});
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Which version of `pg` are you using?

Comment: There is no check for `err` on connection, perhaps `done` is not provided in case of error

Comment: @KirillSlatin yeah that was my first guess too, but in that case `client.query()` won't work either (I checked).

Comment: @robertklep pg@0.7.2

Comment: @mysterpaul latest is `4.4.1`

Comment: @robertklep, you're right. Just located that in sources. When there is an error, there is a noop function provided. So there must be no `undefined`

Comment: @robertklep Just updated to 4.4.1, getting a different error, even on SELECT now - now it thinks `callback()` is undefined

Comment: @mysterpaul that sounds like there's something else wrong with your code, `callback` is a function that you define in your own code.

Comment: @robertklep ah, I simply hadn't handled a missing middle parameter in the select statement

Answer (score 0):

Solution was upgrading to 4.4.1.

Comment: Was this the cause of the issue? - >I simply hadn't handled a missing middle parameter in the select statement. If so, then this is not the solution to the problem you published.

Comment: That parameter fix was the cause of the issue that came up with my SELECT after upgrading; upgrading was the solution for the original problem, which I only had for DELETE and INSERT while using the old version.

Comment: If you want a simpler API, without having to use done(), check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) ;)